# How to write Node callbacks with multiple parameters without nesting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm very confused about how to make async function calls to callbacks that require multiple parameters that the initial function might not have access to. For example,

I call `getData` with `count` equal to 3 and `callback` being a second function, `parseData`, which itself requires the data and a `dataSchema`.

```
 const allData = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

function getData(count, callback) {
    if (count <= allData.length) {
        return callback(null, allData.slice(0, count));
    }
    else console.log("no");
}

function parseData(data, dataSchema, callback) {
    // parse data according to schema
}    

getData(3, parseData);
```

`getData` doesn't need to know about `dataSchema`, so how do I provide that information to `parseData` while maintaining async flow?

One option would be:

```
getData(3, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(error);

    else parseData(data, mySchema);
};
```

`dataSchema` might be the structure of the object that we want to organize the data in, an object with enumerations as keys vs a plain array, for example. It's just meant to illustrate that the callback requires additional info that the initial function doesn't need and shouldn't have.

But if there are several operations this approach will lead to complex nesting.

EDIT: I know async/await and promises are a thing but I wanted to understand how this was done before.

Comment: What's `mySchema` in your example? But yes, it can lead to "callback hell," which is one reason that style of API is being replaced with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: `dataSchema` might be the structure of the object that we want to organize the data in, an object with enumerations as keys vs a plain array, for example. It's just meant to illustrate that the callback requires additional info that the initial function doesn't need and shouldn't have.

Comment: Meant to be `count`, the number of values to return. Corrected.

Comment: Where is `dataSchema` defined in your example? Where should it come from? Can you not make an example that is fully runnable and illustrates what goes wrong?

Comment: "*I wanted to understand how this was done before.*" - well, it was done [**with** nesting](http://callbackhell.com)